# Cannot find module 'react-dom' from 'relayUnstableBatchedUpdates.js'

Tags: react-native, jestjs, relayjs, relay

I'm receiving the following error when I try to run a Jest snapshot test on my react-native code

should I create a mock for **Relay**? is there any code example of mocking Relay to work with jest and react-native?

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom' from 'relayUnstableBatchedUpdates.js'
        at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:151:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-relay/lib/relayUnstableBatchedUpdates.js:15:18)
        at new RelayEnvironment (node_modules/react-relay/lib/RelayEnvironment.js:39:63)
```